# How to find variance and count periods until condition is met after event in R

Tags: r, loops

--sorry for the bad title, any suggestions to make it more clear?--

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame( day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
                  score = c(67,51,52,57,66,63,63,68,64,57,77),
                  attempt = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
```

I want to calculate how many days it takes to get over a threshold of >10% in scores each time an attempt occurs. The threshold should only be calculated for scores that occurred after the attempt.

The threshold is simply calculated as the percentage difference from the attempts until the next score which is >10%. For the first value in the table below this would be 57/51-1=0.12

Attempt = `1`

As a result, I would like a table which shows me the actual percentage deviation over the score at the time the attempt as well as the number of days it took.

```
Day Score  Attempt  Threshold   Periods
1    67       0     
2    51       1        12%         1
3    52       0     
4    57       1        16%         0
5    66       0     
6    63       0     
7    63       0     
8    68       1        13%         2
9    64       0     
10   57       0     
11   77       0
```

Comment: How do you calculate the threshold?

Comment: In addition to Katerina's question, shouldn't the first value in `Periods` be equal to 1? Because only 1 period has passed?

Comment: The threshold is the variance between the score at the attempt and the score where the variance is >10%. And yes, maybe setting the score of the period as 1 makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your `threshold` yet, you can calculate it as follows. I'll assume you have some starting point `start_score`:

```
start_score  <- 45
later_scores <- df$score[df$attempt == 1]

target       <- c(start_score, later_scores)
# 45 51 57 68      From these we want to calculate percentage increase:    

# -length(target) to remove the last value of target from the denominator
pct_increase <- (diff(target) / target[-length(target)]) * 100

df$threshold[df$attempt == 1] <- pct_increase
```

With the `threshold` column in place, we can proceed: Find the rows in which `df$threshold > 10`, then precede those indices with a zero and calculate the number of rows (i.e. periods) that are between the rows with `df$threshold > 10`:

```
inds <- c(0, which(df$threshold > 10))

df$periods       <- rep(NA, 11)
df$periods[inds] <- diff(inds)-1

# day score attempt threshold    periods
# 1    67       0        NA      NA
# 2    51       1  13.33333       1
# 3    52       0        NA      NA
# 4    57       1  11.76471       1
# 5    66       0        NA      NA
# 6    63       0        NA      NA
# 7    63       0        NA      NA
# 8    68       1  19.29825       3
# 9    64       0        NA      NA
#10    57       0        NA      NA
#11    77       0        NA      NA
```

**Edit to find sell point 'attempt'**:
The first value in 'df$score' is troublesome for illustration, because if you buy at that point, you'll only be able to sell at +10% in the last period. However, if you have already bought, you should've sold in the first period immediately. Therefore I deleted this value from the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(day = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
                 score = c(51,52,57,66,63,63,68,64,57,77),
                 attempt = c(1, rep(NA, 9)))
```

If I understand correctly, you will sell after a score is reached that is 10% higher than the score in the period in which you bought. Parallel to this, you also immediately buy again in the period you sell, right? So you wait with selling your newly bought shares (?) until the scores have again risen by 10%:

```
sell_time1 <- 1
repeat{  
  sell_thres <- df$score[sell_time1] * 1.1
  sell_time2 <- min( which( (df$score > sell_thres) & (df$day > df$day[sell_time1]) ))
  ifelse(sell_time2 == sell_time1, break, sell_time1 <- sell_time2)
  df$attempt[sell_time1] <- 1
}
```

This will produce a warning, because at some point `sell_time2` in the second line of the `repeat{}` will try to take the minimum value of an empty vector. In this application, this is nothing to worry about. It will result in:

```
#    day  score attempt
#    2    51       1
#    3    52      NA
#    4    57       1
#    5    66       1
#    6    63      NA
#    7    63      NA
#    8    68      NA
#    9    64      NA
#   10    57      NA
#   11    77       1
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to find the threshold first based on the attempt column. For each time there is an attempt, I need to find which attempt below has a variance >10%.

Comment: Can the deviation also be negative 10%? Or are you only looking for increases?

Comment: Only increase, i.e. the first increase which exceeds the 10% threshold.

Comment: And how did you come up with the 12% in the second row? Because as far as I can see from the data you posted, it should be -23,88%

Comment: The 12% is the difference between the first score which was above the 10%, which came after the attempt. Attempt on day 2 (51) and first score higher than 10% on day 4 (57). 57/51= 11.76%

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the starting point would always be the first attempt score. I want to build a model to backtest for an investment strategy, so an attempt represents buying a share, and it will be sold at a threshold of +10%. So I only need to find the score at which the % gain is >10, and the number of periods it took to get there. I think your answer above, is slightly different or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is a bit different in the sense that 'attempt' is treated as given here and the threshold is calculated after attempt. I guess that doesn't make practical sense in the way you just described your problem setting. I'll edit my answer tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the edit and all your help so far. I don't seem to get a result with the warning message? and to your question "Parallel to this, you also immediately buy again in the period you sell, right?", you actually just buy when an attempt = 1 otherwise you don't buy. The results would be similar to my result `df` in the original questions.